# PyCharm can't find the right paths if I open a directory that is not the Django root

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Our projects are usually structured:

```
/project-name
  /src
    /django-project-name
      etc..
readme.md
requirements.txt
```

If I open `/project-name` instead of `/django-project-name` PyCharm underlines my imports saying they can't find and it tries to reference imports as `src.django-project-name.app_name.models.Thing` which can't actually be found when you run Django.

How can I get it to work the same as when I mount `/djang-project-name` where it gets these things right?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I fixed it by going to `File -> Preferences -> Project Structure` selecting the `/django-project-name` in the tree and clicking `sources` to add it.

Comment: You'll also need to enable Django support (settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django -> Enable Django Support).

Comment: The PyCharm documentation clearly states that marking a directory as a "sources" directory will result in that directory being added to PYTHONPATH- but this clearly and repeatedly does not work for me (source: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-structure-dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with PyCharm not finding the templates folder for an existing Django project. So I created a test project and saw that the template folder setting is only added when setting up the project (it should be in project-root/.idea/project-name.iml)

Copying the same setting and changing the folder to the correct one fixed the issue for me.

Comment: you can mark folder as Template folders in PyCharm, that should do the trick too

Answer (score 0):

Python requires an `__init__.py` file in each directory that is a module or part of the project, in pycharm you can add extra paths via preferences

Comment: The _ _ init _ _.py file is no longer mandatory since Python 3.3. Moreover it indicates the interpreter to create a single directory package which shadows sys.path and may lead to import errors if you're not aware of it. See PEP420: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification