# Add django project to python path when developing with pycharm 3.0 community edition Windows7

Tags: python, django, pycharm, pythonpath

I created a new Django project using the cmd line. The directory structure was the following

```
--src
|___project_name
    |
    |__project_folder
    |  |
    |  |__settings.py etc
    |
    |__some_app
    |
    |__another_app  
etc...
```

I opened my Django project using open directory. 
But when I am inside an app(lets say some_app) and try to import another_app.models pycharm editor does see it as an error, thus making it red underlined. But when i run it it works fine. I guess I should have openned the project_name directory and not the src directory above. How can i solve this issue?
I went to settings in my project interpreter but won't let me manually add my paths.

Comment: I am sorry don't bother...followed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909857/how-can-i-get-pycharm-to-find-the-right-paths-if-i-open-a-directory-that-is-not and fixxed it. Ty all :)