# Finding import path in pycharm

Tags: python, import, path, pycharm

I am using pycharm version 3.4 on ubuntu and have a project with the following structure:

`~/project/src/python/utils/sub1/sub2/sub3/my_code.py`

the utils folder also contains an `__init__.py` file which offers a number of utility functions. I want to include some of them, but it wouldn't find it:

```
from project.src.python.utils import read_utf8
```

I followed this post, which seemed to discuss the same problem:
[PyCharm can't find the right paths if I open a directory that is not the Django root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909857/how-can-i-get-pycharm-to-find-the-right-paths-if-i-open-a-directory-that-is-not)

But changing `~/project` to a "source" folder didn't help. This isn't a typo on my side, as it should at least find "project" when trying to import something from it, but

```
import project
```

also gives my an "unresolved reference" error.

---

edit: I should add that I cannot change the code, as it is a shared project. I need that exact import line to work on my machine. My counterpart uses eclipse, were it seems to be easier to add a path to additional code.

Comment: what's the value of `sys.path`? try printing it at the start of the script

Comment: also, the syntax of your import statement is wrong, you should separate the paths with dots rather than forward slashes

Comment: @GP89 my bad, a typo. It's dots in the code

Comment: Try the second answer in the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197970/pycharm-import-external-library

Comment: @Omar thank you very much for pointing me to that answer, the first one actually worked for me, which was a bit less of a hassle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the source isn't in your `PYTHONPATH` which is why you're unable to import it.

python only looks in certain places for py/pyc/pyo etc. files and modules to import (the places are the paths listed in `sys.path`). You can add custom places for it to look with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or in PyCharm under preferenes > project interpreter > configure interpreters, and then adding any paths in the paths section.

I can't tell which folders are actually modules but from the names of the folders I would guess only `utils`. If that's the case add the path `/home/ceca/project/src/python` to the list of paths in PyCharm and in your code `from utils import read_utf8`

Comment: You are right, except that the free version of pyCharm doesn't include the "configure interpreter" option, as explained in the link offered by Omar. Apart from that, everything is as you said, and my project works now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ArneRecknagel np. I'm running 3.1- it looks like the preferences might have changed since

Comment: huh, what a strange thing to remove. It seems that it's an option which is used quite often, the more visible the better. But what do I know